# Shell script prints more values than I want

Tags: bash, shell

This is the script:

```
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=","
while read f1 f2 f3 f4
do
        echo $f4,
done < users_test.csv
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

And the target file looks like this:

```
Type,Name,Email,User ID,Signed up,Last seen,Web sessions,Country,City
```

I need to get only the 4th value (under `User ID`). But with the script that I have written, I get the 4th value and everything after it.

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.theunixschool.com/2012/05/shell-read-text-or-csv-file-and-extract.html). Any heads up on that one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use placeholder read variable `_` to consume everything after 4th columns like this:

```
while IFS=, read -r f1 f2 f3 f4 _
do
   echo "$f4,"
done < users_test.csv
```

Also there is no need to set `IFS` globally and saving it as you can use `IFS=,` just before `read` and it will only affect `read` call.